# can't push my object to std::vector - gcc can't find something like copy-construct

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm using such field:

```
std::vector<OneItemIndex> oneItemIndexes;
```

This is part of OneItemIndex declaration:

```
class OneItemIndex : public CustomIndex
{
public:
    OneItemIndex(int instrumentId_);
    ~OneItemIndex(void);
    OneItemIndex(OneItemIndex& rhs);
    ...
```

In VC++ this compiles just fine, but in gcc I receive such compilation error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/vector:62:0,
                 from ../IndexesStorage.h:4,
                 from ../IndexesStorage.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = OneItemIndex; _Args = {OneItemIndex}]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:75:53:   required from ‘static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<OneItemIndex*>; _ForwardIterator = OneItemIndex*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:117:41:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<OneItemIndex*>; _ForwardIterator = OneItemIndex*]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:258:63:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<OneItemIndex*>; _ForwardIterator = OneItemIndex*; _Tp = OneItemIndex]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:1142:29:   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_allocate_and_copy(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, _ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _ForwardIterator = std::move_iterator<OneItemIndex*>; _Tp = OneItemIndex; _Alloc = std::allocator<OneItemIndex>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = OneItemIndex*; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/vector.tcc:75:70:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reserve(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = OneItemIndex; _Alloc = std::allocator<OneItemIndex>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
../IndexesStorage.cpp:197:55:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘OneItemIndex::OneItemIndex(OneItemIndex)’
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: note: candidates are:
In file included from ../IndexesStorage.h:7:0,
                 from ../IndexesStorage.cpp:1:
../OneItemIndex.h:13:2: note: OneItemIndex::OneItemIndex(OneItemIndex&)
  OneItemIndex(OneItemIndex& rhs);
  ^
../OneItemIndex.h:13:2: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘OneItemIndex’ to ‘OneItemIndex&’
../OneItemIndex.h:8:2: note: OneItemIndex::OneItemIndex(int)
  OneItemIndex(int instrumentId_);
  ^
../OneItemIndex.h:8:2: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘OneItemIndex’ to ‘int’
```

Why gcc asks for `OneItemIndex::OneItemIndex(OneItemIndex)`? Should I add such construction, how to implement it?

Comment: Your copy-constructor's parameter should be `const`.

Comment: I expect you are trying to copy construct `OneItemIndex` from a temporary.  You can't bind a temporary to a non const reference.

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks it works. why VC++ allows it?

Comment: @javapowered You might be using an old version of MSVC that has this bug or "extension".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
OneItemIndex(OneItemIndex& rhs);
```

to

```
OneItemIndex(OneItemIndex const& rhs);
```

in the class definition.